# File Space Consumed by a Folder that I Mounted A Disk On to

Tags: linux

On my server machine I have to directories, my solid state and my hdd. When I mounted my HDD to a folder that already had contents the mount had overwrote what was already in that folder... Or so I had thought.

There are currently backups that consume around 40 gig in that folder, even though it tells me that it is empty (via FTP).

Is there anyways to remove the "ghost"-backups?

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the drive. The contents of the directory will be restored. Remove the files, and remount the directory.